# Why is the length spectrum called a spectrum?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, terminology, teichmuller-theory

Given a hyperbolic surface $X$, one considers the multiset of lengths of closed primitive geodesics. This multiset is called the *length spectrum* $\mathcal{L}(X)$.

**Question:** is $\mathcal{L}(X)$ a spectrum of some (differential) operator? In what context does this operator naturally arise?

I hope that there are not only folklore arguments of a philosophical nature, but specific constructions leading to such a term.

Comment: I have no idea about this particular case, but the English word "spectrum" is a more general term than something which just applies to operators (e.g., think of the light spectrum in physics, or even within math, think of spectra in algebraic topology).

Comment: One simple calculation that might be suggestive: in a torus ${\bf R}^d/\Lambda$ with the Euclidean metric, the length spectrum is the set of squares of magnitudes of (irreducible) elements of the lattice $\Lambda$, while the spectrum of the Laplacian is the set of squares of magnitudes of elements of the dual lattice $\Lambda^*$.  (Admittedly, this is not a hyperbolic manifold, though.)

Comment: Another possible connection is that there is an analogy between primitive geodesics and primes (see e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_geodesic ), and prime numbers are basically the spectrum of the integers (in the algebraic sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring ).

Comment: Think of the spectrum of a hydrogen atom.  Basically, it's a bunch of points on the real line, if you think of the real line as being frequencies of light.   The length spectrum of a surface is again essentially just a bunch of points on the real line.  So the comparison is pretty direct.

Comment: @RyanBudney You are simply talking about a subset of the line. This subset can just as well be called a “length support” or a “length generator”, using other comparisons

Comment: I am far from an expert here, but taking the question literally, you could have a look at [Bismut's work on the hypoelliptic Laplacian](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7rrxw), which, loosely speaking, deals with a family of operators that interpolates between the (Hodge) Laplacian and the generator of geodesic flow. In this way it provides a link between the Laplace spectrum and the length spectrum (in particular, chapter 8 deals with proving the Selberg trace formula in this way).

Comment: There are also notions of Markov and Lagrange spectra, which are related to height (instead of length) of geodesics in the modular surface. However, I am not sure that the vocabulary of spectrum for these predates the length spectrum.

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev: true, but it's called a spectrum in physics.  So it's natural to do it in math as well.  Mathematics does not have any special rights when it comes to the usage of the word "spectrum".  I mean, think of how much mathematicians appropriate the word "quantum".

Answer (score 12):

I do not know of such an operator.  But there is the following lovely theorem of [Huber](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01369663):

**Theorem:** Two compact hyperbolic surfaces have the same spectrum of the Laplacian if and only if they have the same (a) area and (b) length spectrum.

For example, here are Burrin's [lecture notes](https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2021/fs/401-4118-21L/ex/spectral.pdf) from a class at ETH — see Section 6.2.

Comment: thanks! possibly this is the truly reason!

Comment: One could also mention the Selberg trace formula which directly relates the Laplace spectrum and the length spectrum for a hyperbolic surface.